# Getting this error about Else statement in the batchfile

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I'm trying to run a batch file to map the printers for users based on the IP address of their machine.

Here's the code and the "Else wasn't expected" error.

```
for %a in (50,51) do (  IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4.*: 10\.0\.%a\.*">Nul 2>&1 && call \\domain\netlogon\sydprintmap.bat
More?   ) else (
```

> else was unexpected at this time.

```
 goto Mel )

  :Mel

  for %a in (0,5,1) do (  IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4.*: 10\.0\.%a\.*">Nul 2>&1 && call \\domain\netlogon\melprintmap.bat
More?   ) else (
```

> else was unexpected at this time.

```
  goto Wyn )


 :Wyn
  for %a in (60) do (  IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4.*: 10\.0\.%a\.*">Nul 2>&1 && call \\domain\netlogon\wynprintmap.bat
More?   ) else (
```

> else was unexpected at this time.

```
  goto Adl )


:Adl
  for %a in (100) do (  IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4.*: 10\.0\.%a\.*">Nul 2>&1 && call \\domain\netlogon\adlprintmap.bat
```

> ```
> More?   )
>
> pause
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

Why Else is not expected ? I don't see anything wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Where in the documentation do you see that you can use `ELSE` with the `FOR` command or even by itself?

Comment: hmmm, yeah right. how do I make it as if/ else statement?

Comment: Maybe what you want to use is the conditional operator `||`, which basically means run the commands after this if the previous command failed.  Whereas the `&&` means run this command if the previous command was successful.

Comment: A short syntax example: `echo blue| find "blue" && echo found blue || echo no blue`

Answer (score -1):

For the first part try this;

`for /L %a in (50,1,51) do (
    for /L %b in (1,1,254) do ( 
        IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4.*: 10\.0\.%a\.%b">Nul 2>&1 && call \\domain\netlogon\sydprintmap.bat 
        ) 
    )
goto Mel
:Mel`

Comment: never heard that expansion of `for` variables could be delayed. In other words: it's `%a`, there is no `!a` (in batchfiles: only `%%a`, no `!!a`) Consequentely, you get a syntax error, when you try. I would try searching around Google - and don't belive anything from the internet until you verified it.

Comment: Had a bit of a moment typing from my phone. You're quite right, however, he would likely still need delayed expansion for setting variables within the loop from commands to his variables, otherwise his variables will be empty. I have amended the notation as you mentioned to correctly reflect the for variables.

Comment: Another issue I found with my code, `for %a in (0,5,1) do (  IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4.*: 10\.0\.%a\.*">Nul 2>&1 && call...` the script can't tell between 5 or 50, or 1 and 10. How to limit it to check for one digit only? should i put it like `for %a in ("0", "1", "1") ?`

Comment: One way around this would be to set a list of numbers you want %a to be in that part of the script.

You could say `set list=1 2 3 4 5`

Then you can say `for %a in (%list%) do ( IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4.*: 10\.0\.%a\.*">Nul 2>&1 && call... ` and give it an explicit list of numbers to use as %a

However, if you want to scan from IP 10.10.1-50.* then you could simply do `for /L %a in (1,1,50) do ( echo %a )`

Comment: your REGEX is not quite correct: `"IPv4.*: 10\.0\.%a\.*"`. The `\.` means "a literal dot" and `*` "zero or more of them". What you want is `"IPv4.*:  10\.0\.%a\..*"` (a literal dot, zero or more of "any char").

Comment: That's a whole different question entirely though I think, Stephan.